# How to get information if folder belongs a specific root folder with Api to Rally using java

Tags: java, api, rally

I'm trying to upload test cases to Rally with its api, I need to upload a specific root folder (eg Rootfolder1), the test cases are organized in folder levels (these levels are present in rally too), but my problem is that  there are some folders with same name in others root folders (eg RootFolder23)
eg TC1 must be uploaded to folder Rootfolder1>folderA.1>folderA.1
but the name folderA.1 is present in another RootFolder: Rooffolder23>folder23.1>folder23.Requirements>folderA.1
how can I get the right reference to folderA.1 (only to upload inside  Rootfodler1) in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Per object model in [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) documentation TestFolder has a Parent property that points to its parent TestFolder.

See a java example [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/addTCtoTFwith3TF.java) in response to the question about [Creating >= 3 generation deep Test Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288059/creating-3-generation-deep-test-folders/24292263#24292263)

Also if names are not unique you may identify folders by ObjectID or FormattedID.